# regular expression practise exam don't understand why

Tags: regex

I've come across a practice exam question which asks:

> Give the regular expression for a nine digit number that allows optional hyphens after the second and fifth character

The given answer was:

```
  /^[0-9]{3}\^?[0-9]{2}\^?[0-9]{4}$/
```

I do not understand why it's that. Could someone please explain why? If it's wrong, then what is the correct answer? It doesn't include hyphens - surely there should be a hyphen where the caret is.

Comment: Strange, I would say that is their mistake and it should be `-?` instead of `\^?`, but someone else might know differently. Also, I'm pretty sure their numbering is wrong.

Comment: "surely there should be a hyphen where the karat is" I agree.

Comment: TBH, this sounds like a question you need to ask your teacher / TA / whoever wrote this practice exam.

Comment: Glad to here people agree with me, I thought I was being stupid and couldn't do a simple question

Comment: plus they got the `{2}` and `{3}` mixed up...

Comment: Look to me like a teacher who thought about changing the question from last year, but did not update his correction accordingly. See my detailed answer for explanations. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It doesn't include hyphens - surely there should be a hyphen where the caret is.

Yes indeed.

> If it's wrong, then what is the correct answer?

```
/^[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}$/
```

or

```
/^\d{2}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$/
```

Answer (score 3):

### Is it correct: No

It's quite easy to check the answer that was given to you on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/j8LItOq8dXqUkTHh):

```
^[0-9]{3}\^?[0-9]{2}\^?[0-9]{4}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The first `^` makes sure you match the beginning of a line, and the last `$` matches the end of that same line. It does match a number of 9 digits total (a first group of 3, then a group of 2 and finally a group of 4 digits). It does allow for optional character `^` after the third and fifth characters. I therefore see two mistakes in the given answer:

- Wrong character `^` instead of `-`
- Wrong position: after 3rd and 5th instead of 2nd and 5th.

For instance, the following examples would be accepted while they are not correct:

- `12345^6789`
- `123^456789`
- `123^45^6789`

---

### Correct answer

With as little change as possible, you could get to something right with [this](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KWbqxImNYLzMMfLi):

```
^[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

I simply changed the counters, to allow the optional character after the 2nd and 5th digits, and made sure the separator was `-`.

For instance, the following would be accepted now, as they should (while the given answer would refuse them!):

- `12345-6789`
- `12-3456789`
- `12-345-6789`

---

### Better answer

*You can probably replace [0-9] with \d, the shortcut for "digits".*

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a much simpler Regex:

```
^\d{2}-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$
     ^ - optional dash after the 2nd character
            ^ - optional dash after the 5th character
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YXVMvwWSMgYKDRsL)

And to speak to the comment made by O. R. Mapper, if that's **supposed** to be a viable Regex, based on the problem statement, ***it's not.***

Comment: I think the question is not what the correct/shortest regex would be, but why the presented regex is supposed to be a solution.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: and if that's the question then I guess the answer is it's **not** a solution.

Comment: @ChrisForrence: Granted, I did miss that subquestion. Undid my downvote.

Comment: You need to add `^` and `$` anchors to each end. As-is your regex will result in false positive matches to non-conforming strings such as: `11112-345-6789000`